# How can I directly embed a DirectShow Push Source filter in an EXE?

Tags: delphi, filter, directshow, dspack

I have a Delphi 6 program that receives audio from an external program via a socket.  Now I want to feed that audio to a DirectShow filter graph I create that routes that audio to different output filters on the PC.  I am using DSPACK for my DirectShow filter graph work.  I'll be using one of the DSPACK examples that shows how to create a Push Source Filter as my starting point.

Is it possible to embed a DirectShow filter directly into my main EXE, or do I have to create an external DLL or AX file and run regsvr32 on it?  I'd like to avoid creating an external module otherwise I'll have to create a parameter and data passing bridge between it and my main program and I'd prefer to eliminate that work.  I'm wondering if there is a way to simply include the push source filter code in my main program and finesse Windows into working with it as a DirectShow filter if that is at all possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters don't have to be put into libraries (DLL), and they don't have to be even registered COM objects, no. As mentioned, the only reason to make this, is to make the filter available to applications through CoCreateInstance and/or through enumeration of DirectShow categories.

Being put into your application directly, it has to implement `IBaseFilter` and you will `IFilterGraph::AddFilter` it into the graph. An advantage of having filter privately, is that you don't need to implement communication between application and filter through COM interface, and you can use native/direct pointers.

See also Geraint's post [Using Filters Without Registration](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2011/June/UnregisteredFilters.htm).

Comment: Thanks @Roman R.  That article you linked to was just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only reason to put your filters in a DLL is to be able to use them in multiple programs. On the other hand, if you were to put your filters into a DLL you could always have them implement an inferface that you QI for when you need it.

In my work, I had to play movies that were stored within a proprietary archive file. I made a source that had an output pin that described its media format properly, and the rest worked automatically, if I wanted it to. I also needed to use a proprietary renderer for the video. All this stuff was built into the .exe which was written in C++